# entity Reference with select list doesn't show results

Tags: 7, entities

i'v created a content type with a entity reference field - select list.
in the field settings i'v choose the desired content types for the select list. the preview select list was populated with all the wanted data.
when i create a new content of the above content type the select list of the entity reference is not populated. the only option i have is -none-.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem was due to the fact that the site has two languages. had to enable the second language in order to make the it work properly.